# xltabular with enumitem shorten length

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, xtab

I have the following table:

[image]

Created from the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % Con este paquete se establece el idioma español
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Proporciona flexibilidad en cuento al uso de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, array}

\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=CCE\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}


\newcounter{currentcontenidos}              
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  
       c@{}}
       
\caption{Resumen de las competencias específicas trabajadas en esta UD y sus criterios de evaluación asociados (los DO se indican entre paréntesis).}
\label{tab:CompetenciascriteriosDO}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Competencias específicas} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación}  \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\thead{Competencias específicas} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead

\begin{mycontenidos}[series] % use the optional argument "series"  for the first mycontenidos environment in the table only.
\item \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Aplicar las leyes y teorías científicas en el análisis de fenómenos fisicoquímicos cotidianos, comprendiendo las causas y explicándolas utilizando diversidad de medios. (STEM2)
\item Resolver problemas físicoquímicos planteados a partir de situaciones cotidianas, aplicando las leyes y teorías científicas para encontrar y argumentar las soluciones, expresando adecuadamente los resultados. (STEM1, STEM2)
\item Identificar situaciones problemáticas en el entorno cotidiano, emprender iniciativas y buscar soluciones sostenibles desde la física y la química, analizando críticamente el impacto producido en la sociedad y el medioambiente.(STEM5, CPSAA1.2, CE1)
\end{mytabenum} 
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Formular y verificar hipótesis sobre problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas para validar hipótesis. (STEM1, STEM2, CE1)
\item Utilizar métodos para encontrar la respuesta a un problema, asegurándose de la coherencia de los resultados. (STEM2, CPSAA4)
\item Integrar las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas en el proceso de validación de hipótesis, aplicando relaciones cuali y cuantitativas entre variables. (STEM1, STEM2)
\end{mytabenum} 
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Utilizar y relacionar diferentes sistemas de unidades, empleado correctamente su notación y equivalencias, prestando especial atención a las diferentes unidades de velocidad y tiempo (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Nombrar y formular correctamente sustancias simples, iones y compuestos químicos inorgánicos y orgánicos utilizando las normas de la IUPAC. (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Emplear diferentes formatos para interpretar y expresar la información relativa a un proceso fisicoquímico, relacionando entre sí la información que contienen y extrayendo de él lo más relevante durante la resolución de un problema. (STEM4, CD2, CPSAA4)
\item Poner en práctica los conocimientos adquiridos mediante experimentación, comprendiendo la importancia en el progreso científico (CCL5, STEM4)
\item 
\end{mytabenum}
\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

As the first column does not have any text (I only want the CCEX to appear), I want the second column to have a larger width to shorten the table and reduce void space. However, I´ve tried and I didn´t get anything.

Comment: Why are you marking the first column as an `X` column when you do not want that? Use `l` and it will have the natual width of the header of that column (as that is the widest), the rest of the width will then go to the X` column.

Comment: Changing the ```X``` for ```l``` in the first column gives an error.

Comment: I suggest you (a) load the `calc` package and (b) change `{@{} >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X c@{}}` to `{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{\widthof{Competencias}} >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}`.

Comment: Off-topic: (i) Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`; load just the latter package. (ii) `left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `hmargin=2cm, vmargin=3cm`.

Comment: Also your code does not even compile without errors. I get an error on `\thead`

Comment: @daleif - That's because the OP failed to include the instruction `\usepackage{makecell}` in the sample code. That said, the `\thead` wrappers do nothing useful in the code and really should be omitted. To be sure, I omitted the `\thead` wrappers in my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would appear to be needlessly complicated, with nested inner and outer environments and invisible `\textcolor{white}{aaaa}`-type objects (the latter to avoid getting complaints about empty list items). The following code simplifies and decrufts the setup. It also drastically reduces the width of the first column -- it's now just wide enough to ensure that the header cell occupies no more than two lines -- and thus also greatly increases the usable width of the second column. As a result of this change, the entire table now fits easily on a single page.

And can you please do something about the green color of the horizontal rules? Do the rules really have to be green, of all colors?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowdays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, calc}
%\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66} % that's the default, no?

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum,1]{leftmargin = *, nosep,
      label  = \thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.,
      before = \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
      after  = \end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\RaggedRight}p{\widthof{Competencias}}
       >{\RaggedRight}X  
       @{}}
       
\caption{Resumen de las competencias específicas trabajadas en esta UD y sus criterios de evaluación asociados (los DO se indican entre paréntesis).}
\label{tab:CompetenciascriteriosDO}\\
\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
Competencias específicas & Criterios de Evaluación \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
Competencias específicas & Criterios de Evaluación \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\bottomrule 
\endlastfoot

\arrayrulecolor{black}

\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{1}
CCE\thecurrentcontenidos. & 

\begin{tabenum}
\item Aplicar las leyes y teorías científicas en el análisis de fenómenos fisicoquímicos cotidianos, comprendiendo las causas y explicándolas utilizando diversidad de medios. (STEM2)
\item Resolver problemas físicoquímicos planteados a partir de situaciones cotidianas, aplicando las leyes y teorías científicas para encontrar y argumentar las soluciones, expresando adecuadamente los resultados. (STEM1, STEM2)
\item Identificar situaciones problemáticas en el entorno cotidiano, emprender iniciativas y buscar soluciones sostenibles desde la física y la química, analizando críticamente el impacto producido en la sociedad y el medioambiente.(STEM5, CPSAA1.2, CE1)
\end{tabenum} \\

\addlinespace
\stepcounter{currentcontenidos}
CCE\thecurrentcontenidos. &
\begin{tabenum}
\item Formular y verificar hipótesis sobre problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas para validar hipótesis. (STEM1, STEM2, CE1)
\item Utilizar métodos para encontrar la respuesta a un problema, asegurándose de la coherencia de los resultados. (STEM2, CPSAA4)
\item Integrar las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas en el proceso de validación de hipótesis, aplicando relaciones cuali y cuantitativas entre variables. (STEM1, STEM2)
\end{tabenum} \\

\addlinespace
\stepcounter{currentcontenidos}
CCE\thecurrentcontenidos. &
\begin{tabenum}
\item Utilizar y relacionar diferentes sistemas de unidades, empleado correctamente su notación y equivalencias, prestando especial atención a las diferentes unidades de velocidad y tiempo (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Nombrar y formular correctamente sustancias simples, iones y compuestos químicos inorgánicos y orgánicos utilizando las normas de la IUPAC. (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Emplear diferentes formatos para interpretar y expresar la información relativa a un proceso fisicoquímico, relacionando entre sí la información que contienen y extrayendo de él lo más relevante durante la resolución de un problema. (STEM4, CD2, CPSAA4)
\item Poner en práctica los conocimientos adquiridos mediante experimentación, comprendiendo la importancia en el progreso científico (CCL5, STEM4)
\end{tabenum} \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The green was a random color, I can change it. However, how do I achieve a justify in the second column and the CCEX to be in the middle of each row?

Comment: @DavidMoldes - Just change the column specification of the second column, from `>{\RaggedRight}X` to just `X`.